# Hybrid app development - best practices around testing

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I got into hybrid app development from web development a little bit too fast, and i'm now in the process of finishing my first mobile app done with Ionic/Cordova.

Though I struggle with it, badly. Not because of the code, but because of the lack of comfort to test the app with each new modification.

It's easy to test data, it's hard to test plugins and making sure everything's working on the device. When it comes to testing Cordova apps, I find myself during this beta testing doing 50% development, 50% testing. Not receiving a push notification? Bad luck! Try to figure out what went wrong in your code and build again, while pray for the best. Didn't work again? Haha!

This kind of development is energy consuming at the very least, each build takes about 15 mins (using intel XDK to build with crosswalk) until it gets installed in the device, and you have to make sure with each build that the code is perfect otherwise you (and the clients) are not happy.

I look at the back-end developer and I feel envious that he can just change a line of code and fully re-test it without spending so much time hoping for the best. So i'm sorry if this question became more like a rant, but **what are the best practices involving testing hybrid apps?**

I'm doing whatever I can so far to avoid building and making sure the code is perfectly ok first, and I have two development environments inside the code for testing and developing. I'm sure there are better practices than this, please let us hear them!

Thanks!

Comment: First, you can use livereload capability. This is not perfect, but allows you to accelerate your development.
Then, you can use Jasmine for unitTests or even Protactor for AngularJS HTML5 ui test.
To test the Cordova part, I've haven't fount better solution than Appium... but still... not very confident in it

Comment: why don't you try a regular cordova project with the crosswalk plugin instead of using intel XDK? 15 minutes is a lot of time and your bottleneck

Comment: there is a built in on device debugger built into intel xdk that test plugins.

Comment: I have no idea. But I will fix ur push notification issue if provide ur code sample? prabhupkitclg@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I did got everything working it was just very time and energy consuming to do all that debugging... @aorfevre I will have a look on Appium thanks

Comment: @jcesarmobile I would have used the simple 2 min android build for testing, but my poor android 4.3 cannot connect to chrome debugging without crosswalk, I would try perhaps to build it with crosswalk in another way without having to download it from the slow Intel servers, good idea thanks!

Comment: @Jess Patton The debugger doesn't test plugins, are you talking about the testing perhaps? I will have a look at it

Comment: @shay i have used the on device debugger to test plug ins before. I am not talking about the emulator but the debugger that runs the app on your device and then connects via adb.